# Datetime conversion error in NetCDF4 file

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf4

I have been using the xarray module to open NetCDF4 data and the matplotlib.plt to visualise the data.

Here is the code:

```
data = xr.open_dataset('path_to_file/file.nc')
l_lat_band = -75
u_lat_band = -70
idxs = np.where((no_nan_lats >= l_lat_band) & (no_nan_lats <= u_lat_band))
xvals = data['time'].values
indxd_data = xvals[idxs[0]]
print(indxd_data[0])
test = nc.date2num(indxd_data[0], units="days since 1899-12-30 00:00:00")
```

The indexing and numpy line works perfectly fine for other datafiles of the same type.

However, when I get to this data entry:

```
1996-10-31T23:21:04.999991808
```

The conversion from date 2 num breaks.

The NetCDF file gives the units as "days since 1899-12-30 00:00:00"

Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: I have since solved my initial bug; it appears that I had some nan values in my original data file, but I don't think that explains why the above data entry cannot undergo a datetime conversion. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "the conversion breaks"? Do you get an error? Is the result wrong?

Comment: I have now added a screenshot of the specific error for my code above.

Comment: ok thanks for the update; from the error I assume the `dtype` of `indxd_data` is '<M8[ns]' (numpy datetime) - what you could try is convert to native Python datetime e.g. via `dt = [datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone.utc) for ts in indxd_data.astype(datetime)/1e9]` with imports `from datetime import datetime, timezone`. After that, date2num should work with `dt` as input.